# Holomorphicity of $\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)+i\cos(\theta)^2$ imply that $\theta$ is constant

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, alternative-proof, harmonic-functions

Suppose $\theta(x,y)$ be a smooth function on a connected domain, taking values in $(0,2\pi]$, and define
$
c=\cos(\theta),s=\sin(\theta).
$
Suppose that the function $f(x,y)=sc+ic^2$ is holomorphic.

> I have a proof that $\theta$ must be constant. I wonder whether there are other, perhaps easier or more conceptual proofs.

---

*My proof:*

The Cauchy–Riemann equations imply that $u=sc,v=c^2$ are harmonic functions. A short computation then gives
$$
0=-\Delta v=2\cos(2\theta)(\theta_x^2+\theta_y^2)+\sin(2\theta)\Delta\theta,
$$
$$
0=\Delta u=-2\sin(2\theta)(\theta_x^2+\theta_y^2)+\cos(2\theta)\Delta\theta,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 2\cos(2\theta) & \sin(2\theta) \\\ -2\sin(2\theta) & \cos(2\theta) \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \theta_x^2+\theta_y^2 \\\ \Delta\theta \end{pmatrix}=0.
$$
The invertibility of the matrix implies that $\theta_x=\theta_y=0$, so $\theta$ is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $sc +ic^2$ maps $(0,2\pi]$ onto a circle. The range of a nonconstant holomorphic function on a connected domain is open in the plane. It follows that your $f$ is constant, which implies $\theta$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks! The image is not actually a circle, since $\theta \mapsto i\cos(\theta)e^{-i\theta}$, but still, this clearly doesn't have an open image. (in fact the image of this map is closed).

Comment: @AsafShachar  Don't we have $cs = (\sin 2t)/2$ and $c^2 = (1+\cos 2t)/2,$ which implies $sc+ic^2$ is a cicle of radius $1/2$ with center at $i/2?$

Comment: Oh, yes you are right! I didn't observe that, and somehow I was thinking only about circles centered around the origin. Thanks for your comment (and for the nice answer).